# adding scrollbar/scrollpane to jframe with multiple jpanels

Tags: swing, scroll, jframe

I have created jframe in which jpanels are added dynamically
what i can't do is scroll down to all the panels which are created.
pls suggest me how to use scroll bar/scrollpane to scroll down the multiple panels.

here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import sun.swing.FilePane;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
public Test() 
{
 getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
 addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
    {
      public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)
      {
       System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    for(double i=10000000;i<90000000;i++)
    {
        if(i%10000000==0)
        {
          getContentPane().add(new z());
          validate();
        }
    }

    setSize(1024,1024);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   new Test();
  }
 }
```

in above code z is class which extends jpanel which have 3 labels and 2 buttons
pls tell me how to scroll down through these panels
or how i can view all the panels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommendations

- Read the [JScrollPane tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) in the Java Swing tutorials.
- Create a JPanel that uses a useful layout, say a GridLayout.
- Create a JScrollPane that holds the above JPanel
- Add the JScrollPane to the JFrame's contentPane at the BorderLayout.CENTER position (Don't make the contentPane use FlowLayout).
- Add your new JPanels to the container JPanel described on the first line of this recommendation.
- `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the container JPanel whenever components are added or removed.

Comment: in above code how can i have panels with different sizes? i have tried setting different sizes of panels but all the panels get same size which is maximum of all.

Comment: @chintan: I'm not sure exactly what you mean based on  your limited description, but I would recommend two things: 1) read the tutorials on how the Swing layout managers work, and if that doesn't fully help 2) ask a new question here together with your [sscce](http://sscce.org).